# How to automatically resize popup window or modal dialog for content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I have an iframe that can appear in a jQuery modal dialog, a popup window, or just as part of a page.  The height of the content of this iframe can change as elements appear and disappear, and I need the containing iframe, along with the modal dialog or popup window where applicable, to change *height* as necessary to be 'just right' for the size of the content.

What's the best way to accomplish this?  You can see the page where I need this behavior [here](http://nerdbank.net/openidux/).

Preferably there would be some event that will fire automatically if any content changes so I don't have to run some method everywhere that I make elements appear or disappear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do something like

```
/* creating jQuery special event to catch DOM content change */
var changeInterval;

jQuery.fn.contentchange = function(fn) {
    return this.bind('contentchange', fn);
};

jQuery.event.special.contentchange = {
    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
        var self = this,
            $this = $(this),
            $originalContent = $this.html();
        changeInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if($originalContent != $this.html()) {
                    $originalContent = $this.html();
                    jQuery.event.special.contentchange.handler.call(self);
            }
        },500);
    },
    teardown: function(namespaces){
        clearInterval(changeInterval);
    },
    handler: function(event) {
        jQuery.event.handle.call(this, {type:'contentchange'})
    }
};
/* end */

/* assigning our special event handler to iframe */ 
var iframe = $('iframe[src="login.htm"]')[0],
    iDoc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument; // we love IE
if (iDoc.document && iDoc.document.body) {
    $(iDoc.document.body).bind('contentchange', function(){
        var currentHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        // we need to change iframe height as well as dialogs height
        iframe.height = currentHeight;
        $('#loginDialog').height(currentHeight);
    })
}    
/* end */
```

Sorry, haven't tested for myself, but (I feel) it'll work.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for writing this up.  Unfortunately outerHeight() is returning 0 all the time.  And I'm not sure the contentchange test will work, since the DOM doesn't change... just the styles of existing elements in order to make them appear/disappear.  Can you advise?

Comment: To solve the problem with outerHeight == 0, try wrap content of body in iframe into a block element like div, and then just catch `contentchange` event for `$(iDoc.document.body).find('div:first')` . Please let me know if it works.